Zenoh turtlesim tutorial
I've been following this instruction. https://zenoh.io/blog/2021-04-28-ros2-integration/
Specifically this part
enter image description here

Run turtlesim node VM Ubuntu machine on same macpro
run the python script on same mac pro but not on Ubuntu machine
I get the following error.
ERROR                net-0 ThreadId(07) zenoh_transport::unicast::establishment::open: Received a close message (reason INVALID) in response to an InitSyn on: tcp/[fd08:84f:e9fc:4a47:43b7:520a:ead3:218f]:50730 => tcp/[fd08:84f:e9fc:4a47:4d0:c49b:c4b2:11de]:64984 at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/zenoh-transport-1.0.0-beta.3/src/unicast/establishment/open.rs:239.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
I expect to be able to send cmd/vel message to the turtlesim node.

This log (Received a close message (reason INVALID)) indicates that you're using 2 different versions of Zenoh which are not compatible.
My guess is your bridge has version 1.0.0-beta.3 (as seen in the log), while your Zenoh Python is 0.11.0 (which is the current stable version installed by pip).
Try to force the update of Zenoh Python to 1.0.0-beta.3 running:
pip install eclipse-zenoh==1.0.0b3 -U
